# console vim in screen session: remap Ctrl-Shift-Left, Ctrl-Shift-Right to not delete lines

Tags: terminal, vim, gnu-screen, keyboard-shortcuts

I have my gvim setup so that I can select word-wise with Ctrl-Shift-Right, Ctrl-Shift-Left etc. (yes, I know it's a bad habit, but it works for me..).

Unfortunately, these key combinations delete text when used in console vim inside a screen session. I believe this is because the two key combinations produce the codes <kbd>Esc</kbd>`[1;6D` and <kbd>Esc</kbd>`[1;6C` on the terminal, which are interpreted as "delete next 6 lines" or "change next lines", respectively.

Is there some way to stop screen or console vim from interpreting these key combinations?

**UPDATE**: Content of my .screenrc:

```
sessionname daku
startup_message off
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%{.bW}%-w%{.rW}%n %t%{-}%+w %=%{..G} %H %{..Y} %m/%d %C%a "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly Vim doesn't have a binding for the key sequence `␛[1;6D` but has one for some other key sequence that begins with `␛[1`, probably `␛[1~` (usually sent by the <kbd>Home</kbd> key). Add remappings to your `.vimrc` to declare that `␛[1;6D` is really <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and so on. I think the following should do the trick:

```
noremap <ESC>[1;6D <C-S-Left>
noremap! <ESC>[1;6D <C-S-Left>
noremap <ESC>[1;6C <C-S-Right>
noremap! <ESC>[1;6C <C-S-Right>
```

Here's what I have in my `.vimrc`:

```
function Allmap(mapping)
  execute 'map' a:mapping
  execute 'map!' a:mapping
endfunction
function Allnoremap(mapping)
  execute 'noremap' a:mapping
  execute 'noremap!' a:mapping
endfunction
call Allmap('<ESC>[6D <C-S-Left>')
call Allmap('<ESC>[6C <C-S-Right>')
call Allnoremap('<C-S-Left> <C-Left>')
call Allnoremap('<C-S-Right> <C-Right>')
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work; see my updated answer.

Comment: @danielkullmann Sorry, I was careless in copying code from my `.vimrc`. I've updated my answer, which still doesn't exactly match yours. Please move your answer from your question to an answer.

Comment: why do you call map twice for each key combination?

Comment: @danielkullmann `:map` and `:map!` cover different modes (normal & friends vs insert & friends).

Comment: In linux, both ctrl+leftarrow and ctrl+rightarrow goes to right position with this answer.

Comment: @Arda The code in my answer doesn't affect what Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right do, only what Ctrl+Shift+Left and Ctrl+Shift+Right do. Also, take care that your terminal may not be sending the same escape sequences as daniel's (they aren't standardized).

Comment: @Gilles Oh I get it, thanks for clarification, I'll dig it further!

Answer (score 0):

This is what is in my `.vimrc` now:

```
if ! has("gui_running")
  noremap  <ESC>[1;6D <C-S-Left>
  inoremap <ESC>[1;6D <C-S-Left>
  noremap  <ESC>[1;6C <C-S-Right>
  inoremap <ESC>[1;6C <C-S-Right>
endif
```

Comment: In linux (ubuntu 14.04, default terminal), both ctrl+leftarrow and ctrl+rightarrow goes to right position with this answer on my case.

Answer (score -1):

Move the binding from ~/.vimrc into ~/.gvimrc.

Comment: This happens everywhere, also on computers where I don't have a .vimrc.

Comment: What is in your .screenrc?